# How to give portal access to a model in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need not loggedin visitors on website module access jobs created on recruitment module in odoo 10 , to see jobs and apply for? 
Thank you...[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public job portal is already enabled in Odoo. you just need to install the website_hr_recruitment module.

[image]

After installing online jobs, public and portal users can see the jobs page on webiste.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you very much.